# Do GLSL geometry shaders work on the GMA X3100 under OSX

Tags: macos, opengl, glsl, geometry-shader

I am trying to use a trivial geometry shader but when run in Shader Builder on a laptop with a GMA X3100 it falls back and uses the software render. According [this document](http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/index.html) the GMA X3100 does support `EXT_geometry_shader4`.

The input is `POINTS` and the output is `LINE_STRIP`.

What would be required to get it to run on the GPU (*if possible*)

```
uniform vec2 offset;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = gl_PositionIn[0];
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = gl_PositionIn[0] + vec4(offset.x,offset.y,0,0);
    EmitVertex();
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Comment: You sure you're on OSX >= 10.5?  Looks like EXT_geometry_shader4 isn't supported in 1.4 and below.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs you link to it certainly appears it should be supported.

You could try

`int hasGEOM = isExtensionSupported("EXT_geometry_shader4");`

If it returns in the affirmative you may have another problem stopping it from working.

Also according to the GLSL Spec (1.20.8) "Any extended behavior must first be enabled.
Directives to control the behavior of the compiler with respect to extensions are declared with the #extension directive"

I didn't see you use this directive in your code so I can suggest

`#extension GL_EXT_geometry_shader4 : enable`

At the top of your shader code block.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this [OpenGL Extensions Viewer](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/index.html) tool *really* helpful in tracking down these sorts of issues. It will certainly allow you to confirm Apple's claims. That said, [wikipedia states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_shader) that official GLSL support for geometry shaders is technically an OpenGL 3.2 feature.

Does anyone know if the [EXT_geometry_shader4](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/geometry_shader4.txt) implementation supports the GLSL syntax, or does it require some hardware or driver specific format?

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, I've heard that the compatibility claims of Intel regarding these integrated GPUs are sometimes overstated or just false. Apparently the X3100 only supports OpenGL 1.4 and below (or so I've heard, take this with a grain of salt, as I can't confirm this).

Answer (score -2):

On my HP Laptop, with an Intel x3100 using Windows 7 x64 drivers (v8.15.10.1930 (9-23-2009)) directly from Intel's website, the extension "EXT_geometry_shader4" (or any variation of it) is NOT supported. I've confirmed this programmatically and using the tool ["GPU Caps Viewer"](http://www.ozone3d.net/gpu_caps_viewer/) (which lists detected supported extensions, amongst other useful things). Since Windows tends to be the primary subject of driver development from any vendor, it's unlikely the OSX driver is any better, and may in fact have even less supported extensions.